# Getting logging/debugging information out of Felix framework?

Tags: debugging, logging, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to [launch the Felix OSGI Framework](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-launching-and-embedding.html#custom-framework-launcher) using `AutoProcessor.process(...)` to load my OSGI bundles. I have specified the directory containing the bundles using the `felix.auto.deploy.dir` property.

When that directory is empty I get no messages at all from Felix. When there are bundles in it I get a not very helpful stack dump.

How does one tell the Felix framework to output logging/debugging information? What I really want is for `AutoProcessor` to tell me which bundle it is working on when the stack dump occurs.

I have tried setting `felix.log.level` to 4; I have tried setting up an `org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener` and an `org.osgi.framework.BundleListener`; and I have tried specifying a `Logger` with `felix.log.logger`; but Felix remains stubbornly taciturn.

So what's the secret trick?

Comment: I started removing the bundles one by one from `felix.auto.deploy.dir`. But the problem remained. The debugger revealed that the same – unreported – error occurred each time. So I concluded that it was not a problem with the bundles I was using. I googled the error (I think `BundleEvent.<init>(...) is missing`) and found the solution: I had two `org.osgi.core`s in my dependencies (the one I wanted and one included by `org.apache.felix.prefs`), so I removed one and all was then OK. Well, actually I proceeded to the next problem, but that's a programmer's life :-)

Comment: I have no answer to the original question though.

Answer (score 2):

After removing the duplicate `org.osgi.core` bundle as mentioned above, I tried once more to set up

1. an `org.osgi.framework.FrameworkListener`,
2. an `org.osgi.framework.BundleListener`, and
3. an `org.osgi.framework.ServiceListener`

on the framework that I had created. All 3 listener types fired and I was able to examine and log information from the events passed in as arguments.

Comment: how did you figure out you had two OSGI core bundles ?

Comment: @treefrog They had different version numbers: there was the core that I had explicitly requsted as a dependency, and there was another that was automatically entered as a dependency of something else.